# Login Failed on SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm having issues connecting to a SQL Server 2014 database using Management Studio with SQL Authentication. This server was just created by my IT department. I restored a database, I added the login with a password, I made sure the server properties had both SQL Authentication and Windows Authentication checked. I made sure the user at the database level is mapped to the login. But when I try to connect using Management Studio I get the following error. However, it works if I use my Windows Authentication account.

[image]

Actually, I kept getting the normal 'Login Failed' message. But this morning I got the above error which is probably more helpful. When I kept trying again, I kept getting the normal Login Failed message.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [this Microsoft TechNet post about the message you received](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175496(v=sql.105).aspx)? It looks like your admin may need to adjust the SQL Server configuration.

Specifically, it looks like you might need to try one of:

> Connect using TCP/IP, or use the SQL Server Configuration Manager to
>   enable remote connections using named pipes.

or...

> Using SQL Server Configuration Manager on the client computer, move
>   TCP before named pipes in the protocol order list.